# How to set frequency of sps and pps in libav

Tags: c, h.264, libav

I am streaming a raw h264 on webrtc. The problem I am facing is that the video only have 2 or 3 sps and pps packets in the very start of the file.
So whenever a viewer joins in the middle of the stream he can't see the video.
I found out that there was a filter for that in ffmpeg called `dump_extra`.
I used that filter with ffmpeg and it did instert sps and pps and the video was playing when someone join from the middle.
The problem I am facing is when I try to use this filter from libav the code just straight up doesn't work.
I doesn't through any errors it successfully generates the packet, but the packets doesn't contain sps or pps.
I looked into the code of dump_extra filter and it is dumping the extradata field from the codeccontext to the avpacket, but my codeccontext extra data field is set to null and extradata_size is zero.
Although it works on the same raw h264 video with ffmpeg it fails with libav, can someone suggest me some code or solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think ffmpeg copies the sps and pps of the first  packet (or the packet that have sps and pps) and puts it in the `extradata`. After which the filter copies that extradata and puts it before every nalu.
I just have to extract extradata from nalu and put it in the `extradata` field of `AVContext`, and then run the `dump_extra` filter.